# asus eeepc 1015CX ubuntu 32 bits or 64bits?

Tags: installation, wubi, 64-bit

i created a bootable thumbdrive that i can use to run on my other laptop, the toshiba qosmio..
however, when i tried to do a run from thumbdrive, it doesnt work.
when i tried installing it
i get this error

> "None Type" object has no attribute 'get_info'
>
> c:\user\hp\Appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04rev266

im not sure what version have i installed on my thumbdrive.
but im suspecting it is a 64bit.

so the question is,
use 64bit or use 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with running 32bit or 64bit. You're running `wubi.exe` on an out of date release (12.04) as opposed to the latest (12.04.2). This makes Wubi fail and unfortunately Wubi doesn't always report the first error, instead it tries to continue and then crashes when it gets a null exception (which is what you got).

If you want Wubi, then run `wubi.exe` standalone - get it from: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ or http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Remove the USB before installing. You can still use that USB to install a normal dual boot.

PS I know wubi.exe is out of date because the revision number in that log file address is 266, whereas the wubi.exe for 12.04.2 is 272 (as at today's date).